# Trying to map a PURL like url to a page

Tags: redirect

I'm trying to map a path such as

```
/BigOffer12345
```

to an actual page such that the numeric part is passed as an argument.

```
/Offers/BigOffer/?id=12345
```

The id passed in will ultimately be used to generate custom content pulled from a remote source (similar to a purl service).

I've been looking into Rewrite, but I'm new to WordPress and I think I'm getting stuck on some basics. Does something like this need to happen in a plugin or is there another interface to get this into WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

If `BigOffer` part is static it can be easyly done with a rewrite rule:

```
add_action('init', 'big_offer_rule');

function big_offer_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^BigOffer([0-9]+)/?','index.php?pagename=bigoffer&offerId=$matches[1]','top');
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'big_offer_vars');

function big_offer_vars( $vars ) {
  return array_merge($vars, array('offerId') );
}
```

After you added this code, **you have to flush rules** going in *Settings -> Permalinks* section in your backend and saving changes.

After that, you have to create a page with the slug: `'bigoffer'`. This page will be opened when you type an url like `http://example.com/BigOffer12345` and the numeric part can be used looking at `get_query_var('offerId')`, something like:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'big_offer_id');

function big_offer_id() {
  if ( is_page('bigoffer') ) {
    // do something... following is just an example
    // the function get_the_content_somewhere_by_id does not exist,
    // just imagine is a function that retrieve the page content using the id
    $offerid = get_query_var('offerId');
    global $offer_content;
    $offer_content = get_the_content_somewhere_by_id($offerid);
  }
}
```

I've used the hook `'template_redirect'` so everything you do in the function is done *before* the page is displayed. Then I used a global variable to store the content retrieved, in this way in the page template you can just `global $offer_content; echo $offer_content;`.

Off course is not *real* code is just a proof of concept.

All this code, can be wrote in a custom plugin (suggested place), or in the `functions.php` of the current theme.